# Wordpress add_meta_box not re-positioning

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I currently have a function in my wordpress-php file like this:

```
add_meta_box('wp_function', 'Event', 'wp_function', 'event', 'normal', 'default');
```

previously, it was this:

```
add_meta_box('wp_function', 'Event', 'wp_function', 'event', 'side', 'default');
```

However, when i changed the fifth parameter ($context) from 'side' to 'normal' it doesn't re-position to the main wrapper. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Try to change `default` to `high`

Comment: @RahilWazir nope still the same :/

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

1. Change it to "advanced" and see if that moves it. If not...
2. Have you ever dragged the meta box around? If so, your dragging customization will override the setting and WordPress will remember where you wanted it. Still change it to "advanced" and then drag it to where you want it. (For new users or anyone who hasn't moved it, it should appear in the proper place.)

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The second possibility was my issue, amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appearently, if you set the position through the parameters within the add_meta_box() function, wordpress will use that. But, if you at any time re-sort the meta-box, the function's position-parameter will be overrided by the new sort you just made.

Comment: Is there a way to clear this option? I'm an admin stuck with an old metabox config, meanwhile new users see the updated metabox positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I could make the metaboxes appear where they should by nuking the wp_usermeta  entries, which all were somehow related to metaboxes.